# Get Sitecore item's publishing settings by version with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sitecore

## Problem

I'd like to be able to get Sitecore Item's Publishing Settings by version to check whether a version is publishable or unpublishable.

### Supporting Details

This can be viewed in Sitecore by navigating to the item, clicking the Publish tab, clicking the Change to view the Publishing Settings, and then in the Versions tab, checking whether the current version is publishable or not.

[image]

### Attempts

I can get the item tab's `publishable` value, but not the version's.

`(get-item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/...path to item").Fields["__Never publish"]`

I've also looked through the available fields and done some searching, but can only find the item's publishability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for `__Hide version` field, it controls an item version publishing. If its value for a certain version is `1` then that version will be prevented from publishing, if it doesn't have any value / empty then the version will be published as usual.

Also, note that `__Valid from` and `__Valid to` fields are responsible for the **version** publishing.

Comment: This is much appreciated.  When I can verify I'll accept!

Comment: Thanks, @w00ngy, I am glad that my advice helped you!